# BitcoinLib usage in c#

Tags: c#

So this is maybe dumb but I am using BitcoinLib for c# and I am trying to get to work this line:

`IBitcoinService BitcoinService = new BitcoinService("https://localhost:5051/", "aaa" ,"aaa","vvvv", 5);`

What I dont know: What to input there. I tried watching videos or documentation but theres anywhere said what website/password/acc and all to input. Then When I know what to input, how can I mine and then send bitcoins to my wallet? I know this is stupid but I really dont understand how to programate it...

What I tried: I have tried reading a documentation, I have tried watching some videos, downloading demo of app and nothing helped me. Either I am dumb or it's complicated.

Btw: I know how mining and bitcoin works (basics)

Comment: Could you link the Documentation or example?

Comment: [Here's the source.](https://github.com/cryptean/bitcoinlib/blob/ae7606445f25d1661590046cf690dac8757a21ff/src/BitcoinLib/Services/Coins/Bitcoin/BitcoinService.cs#L15) You can see the parameters are: daemon URL, RPC username, RPC password and wallet password. (But I don't know Bitcoin well enough to tell you what the RPC is in this context.)

Comment: That class seems to be based entirely around changing the vallet contents. Sending money or changing the valet ID. Client software stuff. It does not seem to actually deal with bitcoin mining or even looking at the ledger. The target computer would be the nearest bitcoin node to you. Actuall code seem to be in teh base class `CoinService` or some of it's predecessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your Bitcoin Core wallet properly in bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcuser = MyRpcUsername
rpcpassword = MyRpcPassword
server=1
txindex=1
```

Then you can just initiate the BitcoinService like that:

```
IBitcoinService BitcoinService = new BitcoinService();
```

and it will work; you don't need to explicitly define them inside the code. If you need to change these parameters in runtime you can do so by calling:

```
(IBitcoinService).Parameters
```